# How to merge rows and form multivalued attributes for a 2 column table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I know this is terrible practice indeed, but I want to use the merged multivalued table for the GUI part of my program. Following is the thing I want.

[raw table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lj0N.png)

to something like

[multivalued merged table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m33wy.png)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Try `Group_concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` for it:

```
select workerid, GROUP_CONCAT(worktype)
from t
group by workerid
```

Look at the fiddle *[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=448f1eb108dea2c9a5714ccf95a797c2)*.

Comment: just a side note for future readers. this does not work for MySQL server.